# Dynamic Lazy Loading using React.Lazy (16.6.0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-async

I get an array like

```
{Path:xxx, 
Component:"./xxx/ComPXX"}
```

from my API and based on that create my application's routes. At the moment I'm using React-Loadable (5.5.0) and React-Router (4.4.0-betax to avoid warnings in strict mode). See working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/184rpk25rl).

Since React 16.6 has introduced React.lazy, I'm trying to migrate my solution, however I'm facing errors and difficulties however I try to do this. You can see migrated (failing) code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3rv3yn0p5p).

Any Idea why this isn't working? Can it be because React.Lazy doesn't accept variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got <strike>2</strike> 3 main issues:

1. In this line:

   ```
   var c = <dynamicLoader component={prop.component} />;
   ```

   [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized). so change it to this:

   ```
   var c = <DynamicLoader component={prop.component} />;
   ```

   Obviously you'll need to change the declaration as well:

   ```
   function DynamicLoader(props) {
     return (
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
         React.lazy(() => import(`${props.component}`))
       </Suspense>
     );
   }
   ```
2. In this line

   ```
   return <Route exact path={prop.path} component={c} key={key} />;
   ```

   As the name of the prop `component` suggests, you need to pass a
   component and not an element you can read more about the difference
   in the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).

   So you'll need to change it to this:

   ```
   return <Route exact path={prop.path} component={() => c} key={key} />;
   ```
3. You are right.   I missed the children part, you are rendering a string.   You can create a
   variable and just render it as the child:

   ```
   function DynamicLoader(props) {
     const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`${props.component}`));
     return (
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
         <LazyComponent/>
       </Suspense>
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I made the changes as you suggested, no more errors. However now when I click on a route instead of seeing the component I see something like "React.lazy(() => import(`$./HomeB`))" instead of the component.

Comment: Sorry! Looks like I forgot to have {} around the React.lazy.. and it was being treated like a string. adding {}, I'm getting errors now. Can you have a look please? Thx
https://codesandbox.io/s/3rv3yn0p5p

Comment: Check the update to the answer, by the way, wrapping it with `{}` won't make it a react element, you'll need to use JSX which is just a syntactic sugar for  [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements)

Comment: I would recommend using the `render` prop of `Route` and not `component` since component calls React.createElement and if you put an inline function there, it will cause a re-render. You can see some more information here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component